# Extract feature(methods, strings etc.) from c# .exe

Tags: c#, parsing, abstract-syntax-tree

I'm looking for a way to extract programmatically information like method declared, functions declared and called, strings et similar from a .exe wrote in c#.
I thought about getting the AST and then analyze it, I've found some examples but they point to dead links. I've tried using the reflection of .NET but I wasn't able to reach what I needed.
Any suggestion?

Example:

input: helloWorld.exe

output:

- String: "Hello World!"
- Declared function: PrintHelloWorld
- called function: PrintHelloWorld, Console.WriteLine

or something similar.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the [ICSharpCode.Decompiler](https://github.com/icsharpcode/ILSpy) library to decompile the methods that you need.

Here an example:

```cs
var assemblyPath = @"MyPath\Demo.ConsoleApp.dll";
var decompiler = new CSharpDecompiler(assemblyPath, new DecompilerSettings());
var name = new FullTypeName("Demo.ConsoleApp.Foo");
ITypeDefinition typeInfo = decompiler.TypeSystem.MainModule.Compilation.FindType(name).GetDefinition();
var tokenOfFirstMethod = typeInfo.Methods.First().MetadataToken;
Console.WriteLine(decompiler.DecompileAsString(tokenOfFirstMethod));
```

And here the [nuget package](https://www.nuget.org/packages/ICSharpCode.Decompiler)